# Download google tile layer maps

Tags: leaflet, google-maps, mapbox, leaflet-draw, esri-leaflet

```
I am using google map in leaflet like this  


            var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
        osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3'],attribution: osmAttrib}),
        leafletMap = new L.Map('mapDiv', {layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(20.6266667,78.749305), zoom: 18 });
```

i want to know how i can download that tile .so that i can genrate offline map
is there any way for that